# Need to update Google contacts of another user using Service Account

Tags: google-api-java-client, google-contacts-api

I have created a service account with which I am able to update Google Sheets. For this, I had to share the google sheet with the service account email id. Now, I want to be able to update the contacts for the user. When I use the credentials, it is updating for the service account user and not the original user. Is there any way to update this using the service account?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try using [Google Contacts API version 3.0](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/). This API allows client applications to view and update a user's contacts.

However, please do note that, to be able to use Google Contacts API, you need to use [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) to authorize requests. And, for server-to-server interactions, you may use [OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) wherein it was mentioned that,

> If you want to access user data for users in your G Suite domain, then delegate domain-wide access to the service account.

In [delegating domain-wide authority](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority):

> If you have delegated domain-wide access to the service account and you want to impersonate a user account, specify the email address of the user account with the `setServiceAccountUser` method of the `GoogleCredential` factory.

Please note that you need to use the `GoogleCredential` object to call Google APIs in your application.

Here's an example on how to delegate domain-wide authority:

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
    .setTransport(httpTransport)
    .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
    .setServiceAccountId(emailAddress)
    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("MyProject.p12"))
    .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(SQLAdminScopes.SQLSERVICE_ADMIN))
    .setServiceAccountUser("user@example.com")
    .build();
```

After obtaining the proper authorization, you may continue with [updating contacts](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#updating_contacts).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks. This is useful. But does this work only if we have a g-suite account? I could do something similar with sheets by just sharing with the service account email id. Anything similar possible with contacts?

Answer (score 0):

No. Contacts can only be edited with a valid authentication session from the account you want to update.